# Potential pitfalls in using a JMS queue?

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, database

I've been asked to design and implement a system for receiving a high volume of automated sensor data from a large number of devices. This data will be produced at regular intervals and sent to the server as xml in an http post. The devices will keep resending the same data if they don't receive a specific acknowledgment from the server. Some potentially heavy duty processing of this data will need to occur before it's inserted to a number of tables in the main database via a transaction, and additionally some data points will need to be enqueued to be re-directed to other external urls.

I'm planning on using a Java application server (leaning towards GlassFish) with a servlet to receive the incoming data. I'd like to implement some kind of queuing mechanism to store the data temporarily so that the response back to the sensor isn't dependent on all the intermediate processing. Separate independent queues are also a requirement for the data re-direction piece. After doing some research the two main options seem to be:

1) Install a database on the app server and use tables for the various queues. The queues would be processed by a Java application, either running in the app server or standalone as it's own service.

2) Use a database backed JMS solution to implement the queuing.

I'm not that familiar with JMS but from what I've read it seems to be the better solution in this case. The primary requirement is that no sensor data ever be lost or dropped from the queue before being processed and that it be processed more or less sequentially. We'd also like to make it easy to halt the processing of some of the queues at certain times but still have them accumulate data and for these messages to never automatically expire.

With strategy 1 it's obvious to me how to meet these requirements but it may be less robust and scalable, and more complex to develop than strategy 2, since I'll need to write my own multi-threaded code to handle the various independent queues. I'm wondering what the potential pitfalls could be in using JMS queues for this purpose since I've never worked with them before.

Data integrity is a big issue so I need to make sure JMS can guarantee no data loss in the event of a server reboot, power outage, or if the queue gets very large for some reason. For instance could a problem completing transactions to the main database for a period of time potentially cause the JVM to run out of memory, crash, and lose all accumulated data? (This would be the nightmare scenario).

Also, I was wondering if there would be any way to pause the JMS queue processing via an app server admin tool or to easily see what's in the queue (I would be enqueuing an object which would be the message xml plus some other data, including timestamp received, etc.) I've read a few posts on here that deal with related issues but wanted to get some direct feedback. Basically I'd like to know of instances (if any) where JMS is not an appropriate queuing solution and if this is one of those cases. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a Java guy at all, but doesn't this imply waiting on a reply-queue for results to respond with?  This would seem to be a deal-breaker if your client protocol is HTTP.  Won't this have to tie up a thread?

Comment: There are actually two separate queuing scenarios I have to deal with. One is a queue to the main database, which would be a connection via a jdbc connection pool. This is what the servlet would write to. The other would contain a subset of this data, which would be put into this separate queue after being successfully processed in the main queue. The consumer of this queue would send the message via http to another site. This would mean that the initial servlet response would be separated by two queues from the result of the http post to the third party site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kaleb's answer talks about the benefits of JMS quite eloquently, but since you're asking about pitfalls, here's what I can think of.

- Not all JMS implementations are equal.  In theory you can use whatever implementation suits your needs, but unless you're prepared to do some serious load testing and failure condition testing, you can't know that a particular implementation isn't going to fail under your particular use case.
- Most JMS use a transactional datastore like a relational database as their back end.  That means that rather than writing directly to whatever datastore you're familiar with, you have to rely on the JMS implementation's extra layer between you and that stored messages.
- While swapping JMS implementations to find the one that perfectly fits your needs may seem like a simple endeavor because of the homogeneous JMS API, the critical features for failure handling, JMS server monitoring, and all the other cool stuff that exists above and beyond messaging is going to be a hassle to deal with if you do change your implementation.

That said, I think you'd be crazy to write to the DB yourself instead of going with JMS.  On the first point, ActiveMQ is a venerable JMS server used in many enterprise environments.  On the second point, the fact is you'd just end up writing that extra layer yourself in order to implement messaging, and your code won't have the benefit of thousands of eyes (or a set of paid developers who's sole job it is to respond to customers and make sure the JMS implementation is solid).  On the third point, well the same ends up being true of your backend datastore.  Use JMS, you'll save yourself trouble in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Jherico. Yeah I was thinking it would probably be foolish to try to come up with my own solution to a problem that's been solved many times before. I just wanted to do a sanity check of the whole scenario before putting a lot of effort a JMS based solution that ended up being the wrong approach. I have some experience writing custom high volume JMeter tests which should come in handy here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go the JMS route, a standalone JMS-compatible message broker (separate from your app server) would be a good choice.  Message brokers range from free open-source (like ActiveMQ at http://activemq.apache.org/ or OpenMQ at https://mq.dev.java.net/), to large-scale commercial solutions (IBM's WebSphere MQ at http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/ is one of the largest).

Message brokers offer guaranteed delivery (provided the server's up and listening), and you can do quite a bit to ensure that the system is fail-safe including integrated backup broker servers and instant power backup.  Broker queues can eventually run out of room if your app server isn't picking up the messages, but you can assign huge queue depth (100's of GB) and have the server send alerts if the messages aren't getting processed and the queue reaches a certain percentage.

Your Java app would then run on a different server entirely, and would connect to the broker and pull messages off of the queue as fast as possible.  If the app server crashes or stops picking up messages for any other reason, the broker would just keep all messages in that queue until the app server begins picking them up again.

Comment: Not to quibble (I'm a big fan of JMS myself), but none of those are really 'pitfalls' per se.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kaleb. I'm going to start experimenting with JMS. I'll probably use what's built-in to GlassFish initially and then when comfortable with that will look into setting up the separate message broker. Just for peace of mind I'll probably also have the previous few days worth of messages logged to a database on the app server just in case. Do you have any good links or books to recommend that would describe this stuff in greater detail?

Comment: @Kaleb does JMS provide the ordering guarantee of messages like FIFO?

Answer (score 0):

You will be wanting to implement a poison message queue in your implementation - this is the place that messages unable to be processed after some number of retries will arrive.

You will probably need to write some code that can examine the messages in that queue and re-send them to the appropriate destination after fixing whatever is causing them to fail.

If sequence of message processing is important, a message ending up in the poison queue could mean all processing is halted until that message is corrected.

As far as fault tolerance goes, you can have multiple instances of the consuming services subscribe to the same queue or topic, providing an ability to continue processing even if one or more instances goes down.

Finally, have a watchdog process that pings the various consumers on your message queue, and if one doesn't respond, have it send a message that results in a new instance being started. In this way, your message processing environment can be somewhat self regulating.